# Having trouble to do if statement for Amazon Lex using AWS Lambda (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to do an if statement for amazon lex where if a user answers 'A' for question 1, user's next question will be question 2 but when user answers 'B', the user is brought to question 3 instead. For example,

**Example 1:**

Lex: "Do you like ice cream?"

User: "Yes"

Lex: "What flavour"?

**Example 2:**

Lex: "Do you like ice cream?"

User: "No"

Lex: "Do you like cake?"

I know I have to do the validation in aws lambda (python) but I am not really sure what the code is for this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, uncheck the require button on lex for that ice cream flavor slot (you can do the validation in lambda).

When the response for ice cream y/n is populated you would check to see if the value is no in which case you would assign the value of the ice cream flavor to N/A and elicit response for the next question.

Comment: the validation and value assignment and elicit response would all happen within lambda function