# Trouble with Amazon Lex chatbot slots

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a chatbot. Chatbot will prompt the question "What is your nationality? (A, B, C)" and if the user says C, I want to straight away end the chat by saying something like "I am sorry, C is not applicable to apply. Only A and B can apply." I know I have to uncheck the "required" checkbox after the said question but I'm not sure what to input in aws lambda for it to happen.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unchecking the required checkbox, in the lambda code do below:

```
# inside dialogcodehook
slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
nation = slots['nation']
if nation == 'C':
    return close('I am sorry, C is not applicable to apply. Only A and B can apply.')
# rest of your code

def close(msg):
"dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": msg
    }
}
```

You may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706177/how-to-give-response-based-on-user-response-in-amazon-lex), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436959/amazon-lex-not-prompting-for-missing-variables-when-using-codehook-validation), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132680/having-trouble-to-do-if-statement-for-amazon-lex-using-aws-lambda-python), [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format) etc..

Play with it and see documentation for other things and comment for further doubts.

Hope it helps.